# How much does a human brain's metabolic rate vary?

Tags: human-anatomy, metabolism

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does brain energy consumption depend on mental activity?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/839/how-does-brain-energy-consumption-depend-on-mental-activity)

Our brains consume about [20%](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC124895/) of our energy when we're at rest. How variable is a human brain's energy consumption? Will thinking harder consume more energy? Does this change significantly when we sleep?

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/839/how-does-brain-energy-consumption-depend-on-mental-activity

Comment: maybe even duplicate.