# Does brain activity generate heat gradients in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neuroanatomy

I'm reading this article on [guiding axon growth using temperature gradient](http://www.kurzweilai.net/growing-new-brains-with-infrared-light), and it mentions that the trajectory of growth of neuron connections can be influenced by temperature gradients as little as 0.1C.

This got me thinking - **does thinking generate heat or increases blood flow enough to create heat gradients within the brain?** If so, this may explain how the brain rewires itself.

Comment: It is well-known that brain activity locally rises blood flow and temperature, and so there is a temperature gradient from the brain tissue (source) to the vascular tissue (sink). But this isn't what you're anticipating, probably.

Comment: I've re-read the article and it actually mentions that heat repels the axon growth(text under the photo). This is indeed not an answer I was anticipating.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the brain's energy consumption depend on mental activity?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/839/how-does-the-brains-energy-consumption-depend-on-mental-activity)